# Real eigenvalues of a matrix over a field of Complex Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to solve a question (exam prep) which asks for **Real** eigenvalues of a matrix. My problem is that the Matrix is given over a field of Complex numbers (as shown on the picture) [Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Uez.png)

Is there a special method for finding eigenvalues for matrices over a field of complex numbers? or can i use the normal method of finding Det(Matrix - IX)v =0  roots. If i use the normal method i get eigenvalue of -1.

Comment: That's actually a real matrix. Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ for tips on how to write maths, including matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only why of finding eigenvalues is solving the characteristic polynomial, doesn't matter over what field your matrices are, they can be over anything. In your case is even easier because the matrix is effectively a real matrix, the fact that is over the complex field means that even if you have some complex eigenvalues you can still diagonalise the matrix. In anyway, you find the eigenvalues by the roots of the characteristic polynomial $$\det(A-\lambda\mathbb{I})=0$$ The problem asks you to take only the eigenvalues s.t. $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, so in this case, being the characteristic polynomial as follows $$-(\lambda+1)(\lambda^2+1)=0\implies\lambda_1 =-1\;\;\lambda_2=i\;\;\lambda_3=-i$$
the answer to your problem is $\lambda_1=-1$.

One way for a complex matrix to have *all* real eigenvalues is if the matrix is *hermitian* for the spectral theorem. See as a simple example the Puli matrices. But it's not the only way. As pointed out by user  Lord Shark the Unknown even the matrix $$\left(\begin{matrix}1&i\\0&-1\end{matrix}\right)$$ has two real eigenvalues.

Comment: Complex matrices may have real eigenvalues without being Hermitian: How about $\pmatrix{1&i\\0&-1}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, that's true! I shouldn't say "the only way" but instead "one way", thanks for letting me know